# System Hangs installing "sudo apt install libdvd-pkg" on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, vlc

When it gets to the white background headed "configuring libdvd-pkg" it hangs and the OK at the bottom of screen does not respond at all.  Does it just take a long time or is something not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate to the OK button, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

All is working. It is a CLI interface that doesn't accept mouse actions.